# System.Threading.Timer not ticking on Windows Server 2003

Tags: c#, .net, timer

I am currently having trouble with a System.Threading.Timer when deploying my Windows Service to a Win2k3 Server.  It works just fine ticking every second (overkill for debugging purposes) on my local machine when I install it, but after I install it to the server, the service starts successfully then never fires the timer event once.  Has anyone run into a situation similar to this before?  Most of my research has turned up issues that were apparently prevalent in .NET 1.1 from forever ago.  Thanks for your time and help.

```
   protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
   {
        int interval = Int32.Parse(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SleepTime"]) * 1000;
        TimerCallback cb = new TimerCallback(ProcessTimerEvent);
        QueueWorker worker = new QueueWorker();
        workTimer = new Timer(cb, worker, interval, 1000);

    }
    private static void ProcessTimerEvent(object obj)
    {
        if (obj is QueueWorker)
        {
            QueueWorker qw = (QueueWorker)obj;
            qw.doWork();
        }
    }
    class QueueWorker
    {
        public void doWork()
        {
           // work happening here
        }
    }
```

**UPDATE:**

I've found that it has something to do with the user that the service needs to run as.  When the service runs as System, the threads work great.  Anyone know what permissions are needed for a user to be able to run the threads?  I've tried using the "Act as part of the operating system" in the local security settings, but that just causes the service to start up then immediately fail when logged in as the user I added.

Comment: Really obvious question: what is the app.Config value for `SleepTime` on the server? Other option: use `System.Timers.Timer` instead.

Comment: I had a System.Timers.Timer before I implemented it this way.  I got the same behavior on my server, service would start then the timer event would never fire.  Then I read that Win 2k3 server does some funny threading stuff and that Timer may not work how I would expect.  The SleepTime value right now is 1 second for my testing purposes.  Later it will be whatever I need it to be when I'm not testing.

Comment: Can you post the links regarding w2k3's behaviour? Can you build a console test app to rule out win service stuff? That would also be much easier to test with `Console.WriteLine`. And, sorry to ask stupid questions, `SleepTime` is 1000 milliseconds = 1 second, right?

Comment: I could probably build a console test app, but I believe the issue with Win2k3 server was the fact that threading in services was the problem to begin with.  And yeah, 1000 ms = 1 s.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A couple of solutions I can suggest:

1. Use a console app and not a windows service. Run your console app from the task scheduler.
2. Build your own timer class. Use your own thread(s) and sleep for your poll interval. On wake, do your work. Then sleep again.

And for completeness, here are some of the articles which detail the actual bug:

- http://support.microsoft.com/?kbid=900822
- http://objectmix.com/dotnet/97213-serious-regression-win2k3-sp1-kills-timers.html
- http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.performance/browse_thread/thread/8f4430b6f6efe829/5224d5666844a215?hl=en
- http://groups.google.com/group/microsoft.public.dotnet.framework.clr/browse_thread/thread/72a5528aba714fa/eeee6f6d9601c90b?hl=en
- http://www.windowskb.com/Uwe/Forum.aspx/virtual-pc/5593/System-Threading-Timers-Not-Firing

Comment: This is a good compilation of information.  I'm going to mark this as the solution so people will know to read these.

Answer (score 1):

The timer might be firing.  You can run DebugView on the target machine:

http://technet.microsoft.com/en-us/sysinternals/bb896647.aspx

Then you can put calls in your code to see what is executing like this:

```
System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("Beginning of Timer event...");

System.Diagnostics.Debug.WriteLine("End of Timer event");
```

Comment: I have an event message to fire when it does, but I'm getting nothing.  Also the work inside of the timer isn't being completed.  I have installed it without the timer, just running the doWork() part, and it behaves as I would expect, even writes out to the event log where it should.  So this is completely related to timers and threading.

Comment: I wonder if the user the service is running under doesn't have access to: ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["SleepTime"]?  It doesn't make sense, but you could hard code a value instead of reading it and see if that helps.

Comment: @mtgibbs21: I'd also suggest making sure that the `OnStart` method actually starts the timer as you expect. You should put in some code that outputs a message when `OnStart` is called, the value of `interval`, and also when `OnStart` exits. It looks to me like the timer isn't being created.

Comment: The `interval` value is being populated correctly and the timer is being instantiated when running as my user.  Just for some reason the `OnStart` method just finishes all the way to the end and the thread is never kicked off for the timer.  Again, running the service as `Local System` fixes the issue of the timer not starting but it is no longer running as the required user to perform its work.

Comment: I have also added this user to the local Administrators on the machine, but that doesn't seem to help.

Answer (score 0):

Alright.  Thanks for all your suggestions on this.  I made a very aggressive log scheme and I believe that the server was killing my threads for some reason.  I added a `GC.KeepAlive(workTimer)` and it seems to have resolved the issue of the timer not ticking.

Just in case someone else runs into this problem, it appears to me that the Local System gets thread priority, but other users can potentially have their threads destroyed for some reason or the other.  Since I don't have complete access to the server that I am deploying this on, I will chalk the fix up to the KeepAlive or the server team fixed something behind my back.

Comment: Glad you found some way to make it work. I've posted some other possible solutions which may or may not be helpful to you (but possibly to others). And some of the articles which detail the bug.